# soup.find() always returns None, beautifullsoup web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to web scraping and don't understand why my code doesn't work ^^'
No matter what data I try to find in twitch, soup.find() and soup.find_all() returns "None" or an empty array, but when I print all the data print(soup) it works (& I'm sure that the elements I search exist on the page). So I don't understand what's going wrong.. I had the same issue on another project it was due to my parser "html.parser" that I replaced by "lxml" and it worked! But it doesn't work for this one. Here is my code hopefully you can see where the problem comes from :)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.twitch.tv'

headers = {
    "User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'
    }

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")

#print(soup.prettify())

offline = soup.find('a', {'class':'side-nav-card__link'})
spans = soup.find_all('a')

for span in spans:
    print(span)

print(offline)
```

PS: I know there is a twitch API that I can use to do the same job, but just want to practice web scraping + if you have other web scraping project ideas feel free to suggest them ^.^

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40146128/beautifulsoup-returns-none-even-though-the-element-exists

Comment: You don't have any 'a' element in that page. If you try ```soup.find_all('path')```, you can see that you have some results printed out.

Comment: Thx for the answers ! You're right it works with "path" @davidacmoreira ! But i clearly see "a" tags in the side navigation bar when I Inspect the page.. I don't understand why it doesn't work :/