# Query does not yield results despite entry exists

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to extract the legal form of the search term, in this example "Fondazione Amici di AMCA" on https://www.zefix.ch/en/search/entity/welcome

The code always yields "No search results found.", despite the entry exists. Where is the mistake?

The expected output is 'Foundation' from https://www.zefix.ch/en/search/entity/list/firm/1151591 (this url emerges when entering the search parameter "Fondazione Amici di AMCA" on https://www.zefix.ch/en/search/entity/welcome

```
import requests  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

search_url = "https://www.zefix.ch/de/search/entity/welcome" search_params = {"name": "Fondazione Amici di AMCA"}

response = requests.get(search_url, params=search_params) soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

# Find the link to the details page for the first search result search_results = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "result-entry"}) if search_results:
    first_result = search_results[0]
    details_link = first_result.find("a", {"class": "list-group-item-1"})
    if details_link:
        details_url = f"https://www.zefix.ch{details_link['href']}"

        # Visit the details page and extract the legal form
        details_response = requests.get(details_url)
        details_soup = BeautifulSoup(details_response.content, "html.parser")
        legal_form = details_soup.find("td", text="Rechtsform:").find_next_sibling("td").get_text(strip=True)

        print(f"The legal form of Fondazione Amici di AMCA is: {legal_form}")
    else:
        print("No link to details page found.") else:
    error_message = soup.find("div", {"class": "no-result-message"})
    if error_message:
        print(error_message.text.strip())
    else:
        print("No search results found.")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BeautifulSoup returns None even though the element exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40146128/beautifulsoup-returns-none-even-though-the-element-exists)

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the exact expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use their Ajax API to get the legal form of the entity from search query:

```py
import requests

legal_forms_url = "https://www.zefix.ch/ZefixREST/api/v1/legalForm.json"
search_api = "https://www.zefix.ch/ZefixREST/api/v1/firm/search.json"

legal_forms = {f["id"]: f for f in requests.get(legal_forms_url).json()}

payload = {
    "languageKey": "en",
    "maxEntries": 30,
    "name": "Fondazione Amici di AMCA",
    "offset": 0,
    "searchType": "exact",
}

data = requests.post(search_api, json=payload).json()
print(legal_forms[data["list"][0]["legalFormId"]]["name"]["en"])
```

Prints:

```
Foundation
```

Comment: I want to implement a for loop to get the legal form for every element in the specified Excel columns. But it yields an error "print(legal_forms[data["list"][0]["legalFormId"]]["name"]["en"])
                      ~~~~^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'list'"

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The data you're looking for is loaded dynamically using javascript so you can't get it directly using `requests`. You need to find the API call (it can be found in the Developer console in your browser under Network/XHR. You may have to do some more research if you're not familiar with those tools).

Once you do that, you get back a JSON which you can easily parse. Note, I did it in English so you may want to change that:

```
import json

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/111.0',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Origin': 'https://www.zefix.ch',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': 'https://www.zefix.ch/en/search/entity/welcome',
}

json_data = {
    'languageKey': 'en',
    'maxEntries': 30,
    'offset': 0,
    'name': 'Fondazione Amici di AMCA',
    'searchType': 'exact',
}

response = requests.post('https://www.zefix.ch/ZefixREST/api/v1/firm/search.json', headers=headers, json=json_data)
zf = response.json()
```

The data is hiding in `zf['list']` which is a one-element list of dictionaries. For example:

```
zf['list'][0]['legalSeat']
```

will return:

```
'Bellinzona'
```

Comment: Thank you. I want to implement a for loop to get the legal form for every element in the specified Excel columns. But it yields an error "print(legal_forms[data["list"][0]["legalFormId"]]["name"]["en"]) ~~~~^^^^^^^^ KeyError: 'list'" How can I solve this?