# div impossible to find with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So I have [this](https://blockworks.co/news/btc-backed-sustainable-token) news article from Blockworks: I'm trying to extract the article content.

The div containing the text I need to get cannot be located by BeautifulSoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
    
response = requests.get('https://blockworks.co/news/btc-backed-sustainable-token')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

# find the div element with the specified class
div_element = soup.find('div', class_='prose prose-purple max-w-none prose-p:text-justify prose-p:mt-0 prose-p:mb-6 prose-h2:text-xl prose-headings:scroll-mt-28 prose-headings:font-normal lg:prose-headings:scroll-mt-[8.5rem] prose-lead:text-purple-500 prose-a:font-base prose-a:border-none prose-a:hover:border-none prose-a:underline prose-pre:rounded-xl prose-pre:bg-purple-900 prose-pre:shadow-lg')

if div_element:
    div_text = div_element.get_text()
    print(div_text)
else:
    print("The div element with the specified class was not found.")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BeautifulSoup returns None even though the element exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40146128/beautifulsoup-returns-none-even-though-the-element-exists)

Answer (score 2):

The reason you don't find the article is because 400 miliseconds after the page has been loaded the actual article gets loaded with JavaScript

I found a json-file, where the article is being stored. I'm not sure how "high-quality" the following code is, but you can get the article with that

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json

response = requests.request(
    "GET","https://blockworks.co/_next/data/EVen7p4U4vzWMsPk2q1N2/price/ada.json?slug=ada")
#soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
data = json.loads(response.text)
get_page = data["pageProps"]["readMoreArticles"][3]
get_article = BeautifulSoup(get_page["content"])
print(get_article)
```

Comment: Interesting. I thought it was Cloudflare blocking me from visiting the site so I just went with Selenium instead.

Your code works fine, but how can I retrieve that link you're requesting from the news article?

Comment: Go to the website and open the DevTool (Press F12, or CTRL + SHIFT + I), go to "Network" and reload the page.

Here you can see a bunch of stuff that is happening and honestly I just copied a word from the article and searched with CTRL + F if that word is inside in any of those files

Comment: Sort  by Size and you will find it quickly

Answer (score 0):

That is a dynamic website, it will not load the data as HTML without Javascript execution. So you need a tricky way to get the data like this:

```py
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get('https://blockworks.co/_next/data/EVen7p4U4vzWMsPk2q1N2/category/business.json?slug=business')
data = json.loads(response.text)
articles = data['pageProps']['articles']
articleContent = articles[0]['content']

# print raw
print(articleContent)

# print only text
articleContentText = BeautifulSoup(articleContent, "html.parser").text
print(articleContentText)
```

The output of raw will print like this:

```html
<p>As the price of bitcoin has stabilized in recent weeks, and notched a notable increase in performance terms over the past seven days, a new joint venture designed to capitalize on institutional interest in ESG Bitcoin initiatives is set to hit the market.</p>
...
<p><strong>Can&#8217;t wait? Get our news the fastest way possible.&nbsp;<a href="https://t.me/blockworks_news" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">Join us on Telegram</a> and follow us on <a href="https://news.google.com/publications/CAAqBwgKMPyTxgswn6_dAw" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">Google News</a>.</strong></p>
<hr class="wp-block-separator">
```

The output of text-only will print like this:

```
As the price of bitcoin has stabilized in recent weeks, and notched a notable increase in performance terms over the past 
seven days, a new joint venture designed to capitalize on institutional interest in ESG Bitcoin initiatives is set to hit 
the market.
...
Can’t wait? Get our news the fastest way possible. Join us on Telegram and follow us on Google News.
```