# How can I use Beautifulsoup get the web html tbody's content?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

Tonight I attempt to get data from 'https://lpl.qq.com/esnew/data/rank.shtml?iGameId=190&sGameType=1,5' and practice my skill by the way. I use beautifulsoup to crawl it.When I see its views, I see it have tbody and tr, but the content I crawled did not have these data ,only have a th.other tr in this table was gone. The picture is placed below[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmsD3.png)[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Odv6I.png)[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiHEm.png)

I search it in network and find someone said the problem is because that tbody is not necessary,another blog said it's because beautifulsoup can't get correct data in dynamic web.But the same thing is they all did not say a clear solution. So I don't how to solve it and get the data I need.Or should I change the crawling method?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BeautifulSoup returns None even though the element exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40146128/beautifulsoup-returns-none-even-though-the-element-exists)

Comment: Please do not post images of code/errors/data. Instead post the code/errors/data as text in a code block. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: sorry，it's my first time ask for help in here. And I sovle the problem in your answer , thanks!

Comment: I forget to add a code that "time.sleep" so The content has not fully loaded.

Answer (score -1):

```
tbody = soup.find('tbody')
tbody_content = tbody.contents
```

Comment: thank you, I have solved the problem by another answer, and it just because I forget to add the code "time.sleep" so the content has not fully loaded